# el php no recibe respuesta POST volleyplus desde android

Tags: android, post

Hola tengo una app con volley plus, envio petición POST a un archivo:text1.php
y he comprobado que la variable $_POST recibe algo pero no recibe 
el parámetro que le mando $_POST["dato1" ]a través de de mi app.

Guardo el resultado en un archivo:vardump.txt y me escribe: a:0:{}
y también lo guardo usando json_decode en vardumpDecode.txt' no guarda nada.

Desde mi app si recibo respuesta: "existe POST"

Si uso el metodo GET si me funciona bien pero me interesa usar POST.

muchas gracias por la ayuda.

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvDato1;

    RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvDato1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDato1);
        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        cargarWebServiceWeb();
    }

    private void cargarWebServiceWeb() {
        String url ="http://192.168.1.10/blog-wp001/text1.php";
        final String dato1 ="este es el dato1";
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                null,
                createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                createMyReqErrorListener()){
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.error.AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("dato1", dato1);
                return params;
            };


        };

        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> createMyReqSuccessListener() {

        return new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                if (response.isNull("dato1")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se encontró dato1 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                tvDato1.setText(response.optString("dato1"));
            }
        };
    }


    private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
        return new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se ha podido conectar con el servidor" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("ERROR", error.toString());
            }
        };
    }

}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dato1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDato1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST)){
    $json["dato1"] = "existe POST";

    $fp = fopen('vardump.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, serialize($_POST));
    fclose($fp);

    $fp = fopen('vardumpDecode.txt', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_decode(serialize($_POST)));
    fclose($fp);



}else{

    $json["dato1"] = "no existe POST";
}

 echo json_encode($json);


 ?>
```

Comment: ¿Si lo pones así: `fwrite($fp,$_POST['dato1']);` tampoco escribe nada en el archivo?

Comment: acabo de poner esa linea de codigo: fwrite($fp,$_POST['dato1']); y me sigue saliendo el mismo resultado en el archivo:vardump.txt y me escribe: a:0:{}